# How to filter fields values collection of selection layer in SQLQueryDialog

Tags: arcobjects

I'm trying to show **SQLQueryDialog** in ArcObjects for selection layer (layer created from feature layer via layer's context menu *Selection -> Create Layer From Selected Features*). When query builder is opened the list of fields values consists of **all** values of the corresponding fields of the layer used for creating selection layer. But in the **Select by Attributes** dialog in ArcMap values are filtered for selection layers (only values of features of the selection layer are shown).

My question is how to filter fields values in SQLQueryBuilder for selection layer